# confused with HTMLParser attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, html-parsing

i have read the `html.parser` documentation, but I cannot find the `anchorlist`        attribute of `HTMLParser` class. Python 2.x has that attribute.

I googled for it, but cannot find an answer. In Python 3.x, does the class `HTMLParser` have it?

Comment: Where did you see this attribute? Do you have a reference to it?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: See http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmllib.html#htmllib.HTMLParser.anchor_bgn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `anchorlist` attribute was part of the [`htmllib.HTMLParser` class](http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmllib.html#htmllib.HTMLParser). The module was deprecated in Python 2.6 and is *not* present in Python 3.

The `html.parser` module in Python 3, on the other hand, was called [`HTMLParser`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html#module-HTMLParser) in Python 2. It does **not** have the `anchorlist` attribute.

You can emulate the attribute by listening for start tag events, for any `a` tag add the `href` attribute (if present) to a list to build the same list:

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser


class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super().__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.archorlist = []

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'a':
            attributes = dict(attrs)
            if "href" in attributes:
                self.anchorlist.append(attributes["href"])
```

Alternatively, use a friendlier API like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to gather link anchors instead.

Comment: The `attrs` argument on `handle_starttag` is actually a list rather than a dictionary, so one has to iterate over the list which contains tuples with name, value, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html?highlight=html%20parse#html.parser.HTMLParser.handle_starttag

Comment: @gforcada: indeed; it's easy enough to turn it into a dictionary where you don't need to expect multiple copies of the attribute. I've done so in an update. Thanks for fixing this for me!